# Django and Angular 2 templateUrl

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I've decided to integrate an existing Angular 2 app into my Django REST project.

1. create Django app with static folder for my frontend:

   urls.py:

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import url
   from frontend import views
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static


   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.index,  name='index'),
   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```

   views.py:

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def index(request):
       """
       Renders the Angular2 SPA
       """
       return render(request, template_name='index.html')
   ```
2. move my Angular 2 app to frontend static folder
3. add static settings in my settings:

   ```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'static'),
   ]

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
   ```
4. make changes in index.html:

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <base href="/">
       <title>PhotoHub</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       {% load staticfiles %}


       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
       <link href="{% static "bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="{% static "bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.core.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="{% static "bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles.css" %}">

       <script src="{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
       <script src="{% static "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
       <script src="{% static "bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.min.js" %}"></script>
       <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
       <script src="{% static "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js" %}"></script>
       <script src="{% static "node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js" %}"></script>
       <script src="{% static "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js" %}"></script>
       <script src="{% static "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" %}"></script>
       <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
       <script src="{% static "systemjs.config.js" %}"></script>
       <script>
         System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
       </script>
     </head>
     <!-- 3. Display the application -->
     <body>
       <photohub></photohub>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. make changes in `systemjs.config.js`:

   ```
   (function (global) {
     System.config({
       //static
       defaultJSExtensions: true,
       paths: {
         // paths serve as alias
         'npm:': 'static/node_modules/'
       },
       // map tells the System loader where to look for things
       map: {
         app: 'static/dist',
         // angular bundles
         '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
         '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
         '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
         '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
         '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
         '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
         '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
         '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
         // other libraries
         'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
         'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
       },
       // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
       packages: {
         app: {
           main: './main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
         rxjs: {
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
         'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
           main: './index.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         }
       }
     });
   })(this);
   ```

The TypeScript files are compiled in `/dist` and templates remained in `/app`. When I used two different servers the path for `templateUrl` look like this:

```
templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
```

now I'm trying to declare `templateUrl` this way, but it doesn't work:

```
templateUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}' + '/app/app.component.html'
```

How to deal with templates urls now?

Response:

> "GET /app/components/login/login.component.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2601
>   Not Found: /app/app.component.html

JavaScript files loaded well:

> "GET /app/components/login/login.component.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2601
>   Not Found: /app/components/register/register.component.html

Comment: That's a lot of useful information to then bail out with *"doesn't work"*.

Answer (score 1):

This solved problem:

```
templateUrl: 'static/app/app.component.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error you're having but you probably should use the `static` tag to make a URL to a static asset in your template:

```
{% load static %}

templateUrl: "{% static '/app/app.component.html' %}"
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static